# Unable to Attach VS code to running container using Remote-Containers extension

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging, vscode-remote

The new remote dev container VS code window opens and then the following error keeps popping up -

```
Could not fetch remote environment
Failed to connect to the remote extension host server (Error:Time limit reached)
```

In the logs, this is where it stops

```
Run in container: for pid in `cd /proc && ls -d [0-9]*`; do { echo $pid ; readlink -f /proc/$pid/cwd ; xargs -0 < /proc/$pid/environ ; xargs -0 < /proc/$pid/cmdline ; } ; echo ; done 2>/dev/null
```

I am using tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6-alpine3.7 image in docker